# How to read calorie and distance from wristbrand?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm try to do my own Mi Band application I can find battery level current time but can't find anything about reading distance and calories from wristbrand . How can I do it? 
This is for current time :

```
let currentTime = CBUUID(string: "2A2B")

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

var manager: CBCentralManager?
var mainPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
var mainCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    self.deviceName.text = peripheral.name
    // https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/
    for service in peripheral.services! {
       if (service.uuid.uuidString == "FEE0") {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            print(service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
   if (service.uuid.uuidString == "FEE0") {
        print(service.uuid.uuidString)

        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            // 1811 nın taşıdığı servisler ve bunların kodu
            print(characteristic.uuid.uuidString)
            print(characteristic)

            if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A2B") {

                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Found Device Name Characteristic")
            } }}

  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    print("*************")

 case currentTime:
        print("Current time : \(String(describing: characteristic))" )
        let value = [UInt8](characteristic.value!)

        print(value)
}
```

When I run this I get

```
[227, 7, 5, 10, 11, 13, 13, 5, 0, 0, 12]
```

So how can I read distance and calories . I searched but couldn't find . Regards!

Comment: If you declare a var as optional, you don't need to set it to nil...it already is. Also, please add a space after the colon on a var declaration. Also, ditch the force unwraps. That's an invitation for an exception.

Comment: I don't have the stuff I'd need to debug a bluetooth device, but I'd put a breakpoint in just above `for characteristic in service.characteristics!` and look poke around in the service object to see what's in there.
`

Comment: I'm already did this but didn't show in code above.Thanks for advice @Adrian